Resistance of a pressure sensor from Wheatstone bridge
How do you get the resistance value from a calibrated Wheatstone bridge circuit?
I want to build a Wheatstone bridge to get the resistance of a pressure sensor. The unknown resistance in the Wheatstone bridge is the pressure sensor.
I know that you can't use the connected multimeter in the Wheatstone bridge to get the resistance of the pressure sensor because the resistance here is very small to get an actual value, so you must use the Voltage parameter instead and get the resistance value somehow from that. You can't use the V=R/I equation because you cannot use the current parameter as well.
So how is it that one can get the Resistance from the output Voltage parameter in the Wheatstone bridge?

Are you asking how to do the circuit analysis, or do you want some sort of handbook equation given known values in the bridge?

More like a handbook equation. I need to know what would be a simple way to get resistance from voltage measurements after each step adding the pressure onto the sensor. My goal is to get a ΔR/R versus pressure change for this pressure sensor but getting ΔR and R I'm not so sure.

@Acrobatic-Ad-168 think about this, the left and right halves of the bridge are isolated from each other

The purpose of the bridge circuit, is that you don't have to measure ΔR/R, since measuring that ratio requires high dynamic range. Instead you'll get a small voltage that's approximately proportional to ΔR itself. Since building an amplifier with the necessary voltage gain is easier. Thus the calibration is in ΔV/V_excitation , rather than ΔR/R. Moreover, practical calibrated bridge elements have extra resistances added to trim balance (zero), and sometimes also to compensate tempco ...

could you share references to the above comment?

you mentioned that it is calibrated, so would that mean that if there is already strain added to the strain gauge (or pressure to the pressure sensor) once I connect my circuit to the gauge/sensor that that value of whatever added pressure or strain is canceled?
